# "membership user" exception when deploying to a new server using AD authentication

Tags: sitecore-client

We are setting up new live servers (Sitecore 8.1, Lucene indexes). Previous tests using our Federated Authentication Provider worked just fine, and I was able to access the Sitecore backend.

After switching to Active Directory (the Sitecore Module), that works perfectly fine on our current live servers, I am unable to even reach the login page for the Sitecore backend.

The stacktrace of the exception is everything I have at the moment:

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Nested Exception

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: membership user
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
at Sitecore.Web.Authentication.TicketManager.HasAccessForLogin(Ticket ticket)
at Sitecore.Web.Authentication.TicketManager.Relogin(String ticketId, Boolean redirect)
at Sitecore.DefaultPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Any clues on what may be going wrong?
What puzzles me is that I'm not even getting to the login screen, as such AD should have no impact whatsoever yet.